# How to extract data from .csv file and create a plot?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a .csv file with 24columns x 514rows of data. Each of these column represent different parameters and I wish to study the trends between different parameters.

I am using genfromtxt to import the data as a numpy array such that I can plot the values of two particular columns(e.g. column 9 against column 11). Here is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data = np.genfromtxt('output_burnin.csv', delimiter=',')

impactparameter=data[:,11]
planetradius=data[:,9]

plt.plot(planetradius,impactparameter,'bo')

plt.title('Impact Parameter vs. Planet Radius')
plt.xlabel('R$_P$/R$_Jup$')
plt.ylabel('b/R$_star$')

plt.show()
```

With this code I encounter an error at line 12:

```
    impactparameter=data[:,11]
IndexError: too many indices
```

What could the problem be in here?

Also, I have been trying to figure out how to give each column a header in the .csv file. So instead of counting the column number, I can just call the name of that particular column when I do the plotting. Is there a way to do this?

I am a complete newbie in Python, any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Look at the `csv` module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html `impactparameter` is a size 1 array, most likely, so it doesn't know how to handle the `[:,11]`. SO something went wrong with file reading i.e. you got a different set of data to what you assumed.

Comment: `print data` will most likely answer your question.

Comment: It sounds like `data` isn't a two-dimensional array. Check `data.shape` to see what it's shape actually is. Depending on how your CSV file is formatted, you may need to use `data.reshape` to get it into the right shape to slice into it like you want to.

Comment: I checked with `data.shape` and the size of my data is [514,]. This is because the columns are separated by blank space instead of commas. I used `split()` to separate the columns and it works now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, I have been trying to figure out how to give each column a header in the .csv file. So instead of counting the column number, I can just call the name of that particular column when I do the plotting. Is there a way to do this?

To give columns in your array names, you need to make it a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

Here's a simple example:

```
a = np.zeros(5, dtype='f4, f4, f4')
a.dtype.names = ('col1', 'col2', 'col3')
print a[0]  # prints [0, 0, 0], the first row (record)
print a['col1']  # prints [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], the first column
```

If you have the column names at the beginning of your CSV file, and set `names=True` in `np.genfromtxt`, then Numpy will automatically create a structured array for you with the correct names.

Comment: Thanks! This works! Though to define the data type the keyword should be written as `dtype=('f4,f4,f4')` instead.